# CSV export result deformation

Tags: powershell, csv

I got this problem im trying to list groups in Active Directory and members in those groups and export result to CSV file. My script works fine but problem is when I try to export those results to CSV each object is placed at one line resulting in one wide column containing all values. I want those results to be separated like 1 property = 1 column classic table.

I tried to export those results to XML and make CSV file out of that CSV but no luck with that.

```
$data = ForEach($server in (Get-ADGroup -Filter * | where { $_.Name -like'*name of server*'  }))
{
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $server.DistinguishedName
}
$data | Export-Csv C:\Users\me\Desktop\users.csv
```

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't show how $data is assigned, so there's really very little to go on here.

Comment: What are you trying to do? pull what information from AD?

Comment: I added the $data assigning and what i trying to do is in mentioned in that text. List group of Users in Active Directory on particular PC name and members in those groups.

Comment: For example if i got Active Directory group SERVER1 it will show users in that group that can do stuff on server SERVER1.

Comment: Works fine for me, doesn't appear in one cell. What are you opening the CSV file in? Not that I can actually understand what this is trying to do.

Comment: Im using MS Excel 2010 what it does is it writes all properties of those objects to 1 column and not separate column for each property. For example you got object with properties Name, Surname, Phone it should make separate columns for Name, Surname etc but instead it create one big string in one column containing all those properties and their values for each object.

Comment: So you are trying to get certain information from all the users in a specific AD group

Comment: Script working fine im tha data that i want problem is with formating those data when i Export them to CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the issue is not with the export, but with the import in Excel. Check what list separator is configured in your system's regional settings.

[image: Regional Settings]

You need to export the CSV with the delimiter set to that character. Assuming it's a semicolon as in the screenshot above you'd have to change

```
$data | Export-Csv C:\Users\me\Desktop\users.csv
```

to

```
$data | Export-Csv C:\Users\me\Desktop\users.csv -Delimiter ';'
```

You may also want to add the `-NoType` parameter.